# Azure Key Vault Nuget Package Error

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-keyvault

I am trying to intigrate azure key vault in my console application that is running on framework 4.5.2.
But i am getting error  when i try to install nuget package "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault".

can you please suggest,why this error comes. i am attaching error snapshot along with application settings.

[image: Error SnapShot]

[image: Application Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to intigrate azure key vault in my console application that is running on framework 4.5.2

According to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault version 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/#) nuget, we could know that dependencies is [NETStandard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault version **2. 0**  is **not** compatible with with .net framework 4.5.2,please have a try to install on **.net framework 4.6.1** or later or .net core 2.0.

**Another way** is that we could use the version  [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault **1.0.2**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/1.0.2) which dependency is .net framework **4.5.1**